# Can the Suggestion spell from the Yuan-Ti Pureblood playable race's Innate Spellcasting trait only be used to target snakes?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, racial-traits, yuan-ti

The [Yuan-Ti Pureblood](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/yuan-ti-pureblood) playable race has the [Innate Spellcasting trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/yuan-ti-pureblood#Yuan-tiPurebloodTraits), whose description states (VGtM, p. 120; emphasis mine):

> You know the *poison spray* cantrip. You can cast *animal friendship*
> an unlimited number of times with this trait, but you can target only
> snakes with it. **Starting at 3rd level, you can also cast
> *suggestion* with this trait.** Once you cast it, you can't do so
> again until you finish a long rest. Charisma is your spellcasting
> ability for these spells.

**Can the Yuan-Ti Pureblood's *suggestion* spell from this trait only be used to target snakes?**

I was under the impression that only the *animal friendship* spell from this trait was limited to only being able to target snakes, while *poison spray* and *suggestion* could be used as stated with no such targeting restrictions.

However, I've run into a DM in organized play who is arguing that *suggestion* is limited to snakes only, and I cannot find any official text anywhere clarifying this.

It doesn't make much sense to me that *suggestion* would only work on snakes when *suggestion* requires the target to understand you. Outside of special circumstances, most snakes would not be able to understand you as a Yuan-Ti... The *animal friendship* part of this ability is the only part that lists this restriction, and it seems to only restrict that spell rather than the entire trait. Otherwise, it would also imply *poison spray* could only be cast on snakes, which is just silly from both a canon and utility sense.

Despite my arguments against it, this DM seems set on his ruling unless I can find something official stating otherwise. Anyone know of any references to this ability I can show him?

Comment: Related: [What is an equivalently powerful replacement spell for the Yuan-Ti's Suggestion spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144414/what-is-an-equivalently-powerful-replacement-spell-for-the-yuan-tis-suggestion)

Answer (score 13):

The text you quote is actually clear on this matter. The limitation is only for the spell *animal friendship*. "With this trait" might be the source of the confusion, but it is not stated that this trait can only be used against snakes. As you say, then it would limit *poison spray* too, which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 13):

In *Volo's Guide to Monsters*, on page 96 under the ["Capture, Not Kill"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/vgtm/monster-lore#CaptureNotKill) section, it indicates that *Suggestion* isn't limited to snakes.

Here's the exact wording:

> They use many methods for capturing enemies, such as poisoning, knocking out an opponent instead of making a killing blow, throwing nets, using magic such as *suggestion*, or restraining them in the coils of a giant snake.

*Suggestion* is used to capture enemies, and snakes aren't generally included among the Yuan-Ti's enemies.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, no such ruling exists.

In the description of the trait, "it" refers to the spell in the sentence it appears in. If the restriction to only snakes applied to *suggestion*, it would be in that sentence also or in its own sentence after both spells.

Nowhere in Volo's or the PHB is a racial trait, class feature, or feat referred to as "it". They are rarely referenced, but when they are, it's always as "this trait" or "this feature".